# What is the earliest possible hook for safely using `is_front_page`?

Tags: hooks, actions

When a page request is made, at what point does `is_front_page` start working? As I recall, if you try using it too early it will always return false.

My assumption is that the `wp` action is the first point that `is_front_page` will work, however, the conditional check for `is_front_page` is part of the `WP_Query` class, so wouldn't `parse_query` then be the earliest safe use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `parse_query()` method of the `WP_Query` class sets the variables on which the conditional tags are based.
The `parse_query` hook are executed before returning from `parse_query()` method, variables are already set (eg. `is_home`, used by `is_front_page()`) and `is_front_page()` **will work**, but function that changes the current state can be hooked to `parse_query` (it's still `parse_query()` method, which sets variables like `is_home`).

Hooks `pre_get_posts` is executed directly after `parse_query`, that is why it is for me the first safe hook to use conditional tags.

**[Conditional Tags in Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags)**

> You can only use conditional query tags after the `posts_selection` action hook in WordPress (the `wp` action hook is the first one through which you can use these conditionals). For themes, this means the conditional tag will never work properly if you are using it in the body of `functions.php`, i.e. outside of a function.
>
> However: if you have a reference to the query object (for example, **from within the `parse_query` or `pre_get_posts` hooks**), **you can use the WP_Query conditional methods** (eg: `$query->is_search()`)