# is_shop, is_home, is_front_page doesn't work for woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, breadcrumb

I tried to remove breadcrumbs from homepage because it looks really ugly, but i can't do this because conditionals don't work. 
*I took that from woocommerce docs

```
add_action( 'init', 'wcc_remove_woo_wc_breadcrumbs' );
function wcc_remove_woo_wc_breadcrumbs() {
    if ( is_home() || is_shop() || is_front_page() ) {
        remove_action( 'woo_main_before', 'woo_display_breadcrumbs', 10 );
    }
}
```

Line

```
 remove_action( 'woo_main_before', 'woo_display_breadcrumbs', 10 );
```

works correct, but unfortunatelly conditional tags don't. Do you have any ida on woocommerce shop page as homepage?

Comment: I guess this is your problem [in the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/): "is_home() uses the global $wp_query WP_Query object. is_home() isn’t usable before the ‘parse_query’ action."

Comment: Is_home and is_front_page  are both same i  think you need to use only one just try   one by one and check which one causing  issue   Also use  wp_reset_query();   first

Comment: If the `woo_main_before` action is executed once per request, you can try change `add_action( 'init', 'wcc_remove_woo_wc_breadcrumbs' );` to `add_action( 'woo_main_before', 'wcc_remove_woo_wc_breadcrumbs', 9 );`.  Maybe [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/334882/what-is-the-earliest-possible-hook-for-safely-using-is-front-page/334893#334893) will prove useful.

Comment: It works in general @nmr but not by condition :D

Answer (score 1):

> For **is_front_page()** and **is_home()** condition:
>
> **Important:** Please note that these functions work only once WordPress is loaded such as on template files or specific action hooks. You can’t just dump these conditionals into functions.php and expect them to work.

Comment: so why did they suggest such solution in documentation?

Comment: In the question these are being called from the init hook. That's not too early, is it?