# Page get parameter doesn't work with is_single() function

Tags: functions, url-rewriting, redirect, rewrite-rules, template-redirect

If exist the page parameter in the blog post, I have to redirect to the 404 page instead of current post URL.
I tried to check the current page type (is singular)  and try to get page parameter in the function.php, but I couldn't. It's doesn't work together. I need to implement it only for blog post.
If possible .htaccess redirect also fine

I tried with this code but it doesn't work. But it's working without the is_single function. When I used is_single functions, the page parameter not returning.

Example Url:
[www.example.com/this-is-my-first-post?page=2](http://www.example.com/this-is-my-first-post?page=2)
[www.example.com/p=22?page=2](http://www.example.com/p=22?page=2)

Thank you for your help.
It's not working

```
add_action('send_headers', 'post_page_param_404_redirect');
function post_page_param_404_redirect() {
        global $wp_query;
        if (is_single() && isset($_GET['page'])) {
                $wp_query->set_404();
                status_header(404);
                get_template_part(404);
                exit();
        }
}
```

When I don't use the is_single function , It's working for all page, but I need it only for the blog post

```
add_action('send_headers', 'post_page_param_404_redirect');
function post_page_param_404_redirect() {
        global $wp_query;
        if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
                $wp_query->set_404();
                status_header(404);
                get_template_part(404);
                exit();
        }
}
```

Comment: `send_headers` is executed too early. `pre_get_posts` is the first hook that conditional tags can be used. [Related question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/334882/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The truth is when `send_headers` action is processing, the `$wp_query` isn't ready yet and you can't use `is_single()` function. But you can use it a bit later. There is a `parse_query` action, that can help you. It starts when the `$wp_query` is ready and comes out right after the `send_headers` action.

Comment: It's worked, thank you so much